# Put Two Divs Side By Side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put my two divs side by side: but the divs beneath them get smushed upwards.  Looking like this:

[image]

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="DSL6">
<h3 class="DSLLocation">DSL 6</h3>
</div>
<div class="DSLInformation">
</div>
<div class="FTTN10">
<h3 class="FTTNLocation">FTTN 10</h3>
</div>
<div class="FTTN15">
<h3 class="FTTNLocation">FTTN 15</h3>
</div>
<div class="FTTN25">
<h3 class="FTTNLocation">FTTN 25</h3>
</div>
<div class="FTTN50">
<h3 class="FTTNLocation">FTTN 50</h3>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.DSL6 {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #D3D3D3;
  float: left;
  clear;
}
.DSLLocation {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.DSLInformation {
  width: 850px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;

}
.FTTNLocation {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.FTTN10 {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #D3D3D3;
}
.FTTN15 {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #D3D3D3;
}
.FTTN25 {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #D3D3D3;
}
.FTTN50 {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #D3D3D3;
}
```

I've looked around, and I've tried different answers (both on other sites, and on Stack Overflow), but alas, no issues found.

What I want:

[image]

Comment: `clear;` isn't a valid CSS property definition.

Comment: It's a valid property, but not a property **value** ... you want "clear: both;" most likely, or "none", "inherit", "left", "right", "initial" ...

Comment: Also, you should probably show *what* you intend to see if you want anyone to offer a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this result because your total width of all div is larger than your screen width. see my modified css, here all the div is inline. And another one is you should use `float: left` for displaying div inline.

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 500px;
}
.DSL6 {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #D3D3D3;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
.DSLLocation {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.DSLInformation {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;  

}
.FTTNLocation {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.FTTN10 {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #D3D3D3;
}
.FTTN15 {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  border-color: #D3D3D3;
}
.FTTN25 {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  border-color: #D3D3D3;
}
.FTTN50 {
  float: left;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: inline;
  border-color: #D3D3D3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="DSL6">
<h3 class="DSLLocation">DSL 6</h3>
</div>
<div class="DSLInformation">
</div>  
<div class="FTTN10">
<h3 class="FTTNLocation">FTTN 10</h3>
</div>
<div class="DSLInformation">
</div>   
</div>
```

**EDIT SUMMARY**

Edited the `html` as the OP's requirement.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to black to be beside All five rows to be side by side so div 1 and 2 are side by side, then below them div 3 and div 4 are side by side, etc,.

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: hi, run my updated code snippet. are you wanted something like this?

Comment: It's still all displaying inline.  I want two inline, then below them 2 inline, etc,.

Comment: hi, me again updated my code snippet. plz have a look is it you were wanted?

Comment: Really close, I want it to go: DSL 6 then the black div beside it; then underneath it FTTN 10 then the black div beside it, etc,.

Comment: Hi there, I edited my original post.  The second picture shows what I want.

Comment: hi, run the snippet, now it is ok?

Comment: Awesome, now I just have to add mroe columns myself.  Thanks!